# How to find the (Most important) responsible Words/ Tokens/ embeddings responsible for the label result of a text classification model in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

Let us suppose I have a model like:

```
class BERT_Subject_Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,out_classes,hidden1=128,hidden2=32,dropout_val=0.2):
      super(BERT_Subject_Classifier, self).__init__()

      self.hidden1 = hidden1
      self.hidden2 = hidden2
      self.dropout_val = dropout_val
      self.logits = logit
      self.bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
      self.out_classes = out_classes
      self.unfreeze_n = unfreeze_n # make the last n layers trainable
      
      self.dropout = nn.Dropout(self.dropout_val)
      self.relu =  nn.ReLU()
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(768,self.hidden1)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden1,self.hidden2)
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(self.hidden2,self.out_classes)

    def forward(self, sent_id, mask):
      _, cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask)
      x = self.fc1(cls_hs)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.dropout(x)
      x = self.fc2(x)
      x = self.dropout(x)
      return self.fc3(x)
```

I train my model and for a new data point `x = ['My Name is Slim Shady']`, I get my label result as  `3`.

My Question is that how can I check which of the words in the sentence were responsible for the the classification? I mean it could be any collection of words. Is there a library or way to check the functionality? Just like shown in the paper and [Tensorflow Implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning) of `show Attend and Tell`, you can get the areas of images where the model is paying attention to. How can I do it for the Text?

Comment: I don't know method for this - so I would test shorter sentences - `'My is Slim Shady'`, `'My Name Slim Shady'`, `'My Name is Shady'`, etc. and later senteces without 2 words, etc. Maybe this way I could say which word (or words) gives better result.

Comment: We can do the same with images by checking the outputs of each layer and getting the gradients heatmap and superimposing it on the image as given in the [this blog](https://www.kaggle.com/aakashnain/what-does-a-cnn-see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. One way to demonstrate which words have the greatest impact is through integrated gradients methods. For PyTorch, one package you can use is Captum. I would check out this page for a good example: https://captum.ai/tutorials/IMDB_TorchText_Interpret

For Tensorflow, one package that you can use is Seldon. I would check out this page for a good example:
https://docs.seldon.io/projects/alibi/en/stable/examples/integrated_gradients_imdb.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Can you please tell me the **METHOD**  used for text? For images it's `saliency map`.

Comment: I believe the answer is integrated gradients.